# Using the chain rule to compute $f_\theta$ given $f_x$ and $f_y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is an exam practice question.

> Suppose that $f(x, y)$ is a function of two variables with $f_x(0, 2) = 2$ and $f_y(0, 2) = -1$. Using the chain rule, compute the numerical value of $f_\theta(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ at $r=2$, $\theta=\pi/2$.

So for this question, I have $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$.

Using the chain rule, I have:
\[
f_\theta(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) = f_x(x,y)\frac d{d\theta}(r\cos\theta) + f_y(x,y)\frac d{d\theta}(r\sin\theta)
\]
\[
f_\theta(2\cos\pi/2, 2\sin\pi/2) = (2)(-2\sin\pi/2) - 1(2\cos\pi/2)
= -4
\]
Do I have the right idea here? Or am I totally off?

Comment: @mathstudent Yes. Your computations are good!

Comment: @Marvis - Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Your working is correct.

Comment: You are totally on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your computations are good! – Marvis Jun 13 at 1:36

Your working is correct. – David Wallace Jun 13 at 2:31

You are totally on. – copper.hat Jun 13 at 2:35

Comment: merged comment-answers into a CW.